# Force MapBox IOS to stay in allowed map bounds even by user location

Tags: ios, swift, mapbox

I restrict pannable area in MapBox IOS by implementing mapview shouldchangefrom delegate according to the documentation https://docs.mapbox.com/ios/maps/examples/constraining-gestures/.

```
public func mapView(_ mapView: MGLMapView, shouldChangeFrom oldCamera: MGLMapCamera, to newCamera: MGLMapCamera) -> Bool {
  
  let currentCamera = mapView.camera
    let newCameraCenter = newCamera.centerCoordinate
     
    mapView.camera = newCamera
    let newVisibleCoordinates = mapView.visibleCoordinateBounds
     
    mapView.camera = currentCamera
     
    let inside = MGLCoordinateInCoordinateBounds(newCameraCenter, self.allowedBounds!)
    let intersects = MGLCoordinateInCoordinateBounds(newVisibleCoordinates.ne, self.allowedBounds!) && MGLCoordinateInCoordinateBounds(newVisibleCoordinates.sw, self.allowedBounds!)
     
    return inside && intersects
  }
```

It works, if the updates by a user interaction, but is does not prevent to update map  by user location change. Show / track user location is a must in my case, but only in the enabled area.

```
mapView.showsUserLocation = showUserLocation
mapView.userTrackingMode = .followWithHeading
```

Is there any way to prevent updating map to a restricted area by user location?

Comment: You could detect when the user goes out of bounds using [GeoSwift.within](https://github.com/GEOSwift/GEOSwift) and move them back to within the bounds.

Comment: Yep, but it results a 'jumping' effect

Comment: What happens if you add [`didUpdateUserLocation`](https://docs.mapbox.com/archive/ios/maps/api/6.3.0/Protocols/MGLMapViewDelegate.html#/c:objc(pl)MGLMapViewDelegate(im)mapView:didUpdateUserLocation:)? Can you intercept it before the location moves?

Comment: Thanks, I solved it, pls check my answer.

Comment: That's glad to hear!!

Answer (score 1):

So, finally I solved it by implementing a custom MGLLocationManager, and set it as mapview's locationmanager. When calling its updateLocation method I filter position by 'restricted' area, and if the pos is not within it, I cancel location update.